# Compare SSMS settings

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

I am wanting to compare the settings of SSMS 2016 installed on two different machines is there an easy way to this instead of pulling up each setting and going through one at a time in the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the *Import & Export Settings Wizard* under the **Tools** menu.

[image]

The resulting file is an xml file.

```
<UserSettings>
    <ApplicationIdentity version="10.0"/>
    <ToolsOptions>
        <ToolsOptionsCategory name="Environment" RegisteredName="Environment">
            <ToolsOptionsSubCategory name="Documents" RegisteredName="Documents" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
                <PropertyValue name="ShowMiscFilesProject">true</PropertyValue>
                <PropertyValue name="AutoloadExternalChanges">false</PropertyValue>
                <PropertyValue name="CheckForConsistentLineEndings">false</PropertyValue>
            ....
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to do this it does not give me the option for XML file it uses .vssettings as the file type. A file type I do not know how to open.

Comment: @ChadPortman the .vssettings file is xml, open it with notepad or your code editor of choice.

Comment: Thank you I am able to open the file now. just have to compare settings now.

Comment: @ChadPortman There is probably someone on SO that knows how you could compare them with sql, but that person is not me. :\